# Memoir Class non truetype font

Tags: memoir, truetype

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Umlaute
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Umlaute
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  %Umlaute
\usepackage{graphicx} %Grafiken mit includegraphics...
\usepackage{epstopdf} % EPS Support
%\usepackage{apalike2} % Zitierstil
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mcode}
\usepackage{listings}
```

[image]

Why is the default font not a true type font and what is the command to use the true type font used in the memoir class documentation. I downloaded the archive however I did not find any line that would define that font explicitly.

Comment: The font definitions are here (but the documentation does not use TrueType-fonts) : http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/doc-src/memfonts.sty

Comment: Not quite sure which font you mean. The documentation of the memoir class is compiled using pdflatex using type 1 postscript fonts (the main body seems to be in urwpalladio). Your document will use the default tex font, i.e. computer modern

Comment: I added the memfonts package and am content now. ArTourter I wasn't aware of that, I thought the class would change the font as well.